# Amazon AWS S3 Uploads from iOS Device

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have been trying to upload images/videos to s3 by following their docs. But, after alot of tries I just keep getting Access Denied error.

I have setup a cognito pool for s3:* access in its UnAuth role. But the problem is I cant get it to work from iOS device. I use AWSTransferManager to create upload function but this is the response i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message> 
<RequestId>DEE11EF134B50C8D</RequestId><HostId>/+qV8CLvPZHi4lIAHrVnKf1sDmWFcFS1dcfMX5XG0yfPG/TIASBfo/T5aGZRZg77wdn7siOrRVc=</HostId></Error>
Upload failed with error: (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain error 11.))
```

**Bucket Policy**-:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1460611228663",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1460611220793",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MY_ACCOUNT_ID:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**IAM UnAuth Role Policy**-:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am stuck at this. Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
let accK = "myaccesskey"
let secretK = "mysecretkey"
let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accK, secretKey: secretK)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AwsRegion, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSS3TransferManager.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "mys3")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "UnAuth role policy"? As per my knowledge, we can define user role policy and bucket policy. ie how we can provide access to user and which access_token able to access the bucket. But I didn't hear about the "UnAuth role policy"? Read here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html

Comment: Thanks. So i have to create an IAM User and add the policy for S3 to that user and then use the access key and secret keys of that user to create credentials in iOS?

Comment: Yes. Right. Also, We can use the access keys and the secret key of root admin.(ie without creating IAM user). But Amazon won't appreciate accessing S3 bucket alone with Admin access keys. It's not best practice. Another point, You don't need to create any credentials in iOS, just use the access and secret key during S3 setup.

Comment: Ok, I tried this but got same error. Adding iOS code.

Comment: Did you check the bucket name and uploading path (should has the same bucket name).?

Comment: Yes, the path and name are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an identity pool and IAM policy configured such that the bucket is accessible by the identity pool's unauth role, the following code should work

```
//Setup credentials
let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: YOUR-IDENTITY-POOL-REGION, identityPoolId: "YOUR-IDENTITY-POOL-ID")

//Setup the service configuration
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)

//Setup the transfer utility configuration
let tuConf = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()

//Register a transfer utility object
AWSS3TransferUtility.register(
with: configuration!,
transferUtilityConfiguration: tuConf,
forKey: "transfer-utility-with-advanced-options"
)

//Look up the transfer utility object from the registry to use for your transfers.
let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "transfer-utility-with-advanced-options")


transferUtility.uploadData(
        testData,
        bucket: "BUCKET",
        key: "KEY",
        contentType: "video/mp4",
        expression: uploadExpression,
        completionHandler: uploadCompletionHandler
        ).continueWith (block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
            XCTAssertNil(task.error)

            return nil
    })
```

Please look at the link I'd posted earlier for further information.

Comment: Could you tell me what bucket policy should I set such that it becomes accessible by IAM role? Would this work - Principal : {"AWS":"my_unauth_role_arn"}

Comment: You don't need to specify a bucket policy on the S3 console. Instead you can go to the IAM console, navigate to unauth role and use the "AttachPolicy" button to setup the access.  For example {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        } ] }

Comment: You mean that I should leave bucket policy blank?

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked. What i did wrong was that even after regitering the configuration, I called default() method while creating the TransferUtility object.

Comment: I had a problem, I am using upper configuration with multipart API but when I upload an image and after the first upload, I am unable to upload the image again, For again uploading I need to restart the app

Answer (score 0):

Using the access key and secret key is one way to go about it. Another way is to setup a Cognito Identity pool and get temporary, short lived, credentials from it to access the bucket. This would be a more secure way and what we recommend as the best practice.

When you create a Cognito Identity pool, it automatically creates 2 roles i.e., the "auth" and the "unauth" role. This is a convenience mechanism as many mobile apps have the notion of a signed-in user and anonymous user ( someone who hasn't yet signed in). At typical example would an ecommerce app that you can use to search and browse and only have to sign in to add to cart/make a purchase.

You can setup either the "auth" or the "unauth" or both roles (depending on your scenario) to have permissions on the bucket and that will enable you to access the buckets via the app. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-integrate-an-existing-bucket.html for more information.

Also, I'd recommend that you use the TransferUtility and not the TransferManager for the S3 uploads/downloads.

Comment: Thats what i was doing. Using cognito to setup a new federated identity and then giving the permission to S3 in the identity's role. Then i tried TransferUtility but i get Error Code 2 (null)

Comment: I am confused on how to create the bucket policy itself and what all things do i have to set in there.

Comment: Can you share the policy you have setup in the identity role?

Comment: I already there in my question IAM policy for unauth role. The same is set for Auth role as well.

Comment: Now I am trying TransferUtility and getting Erro Code 2 (null)

Comment: I am a little confused. From what you shared in the question, you have a bucket policy for the root user, an IAM policy for the Cognito unauth role and using the access key and secret key. Where are you setting the cognito identity pool?   The combinations that I know work are 1) CognitoIdentityPool and an IAM policy for its unauth role 2) CognitoIdentityPool and an IAM policy for its auth role 3)An IAM user and a policy attached to the IAM user.   For 1 and 2, you have to configure the transferutility object with the cognito identity pool. For 3, you have to provide the access/secret.

Comment: Yes, after your comment, I have changed the code. I am using the 1) CognitoIdentityPool and an IAM policy for its unauth role. And using the pool id for configuration setup of TransferUtility.